# GWT development in Eclipse using TOMCAT server

Tags: eclipse, gwt, tomcat

Is there a way, every time i compile my GWT project, to automatically deploy `war` contents to Tomcat's `ROOT` directory?

What's the best environment for *`Eclipse - Tomcat - Gwt`* development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I skip deployment entirely. Set up your project to point at the application folder in the tomcat deploy directory. Add JRebel for automatic class reloading, for additional convenience. It does however require a different folder structure than that generated by the GWT plugin (there is no war folder, the war folder is the root of your project).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However i think that this means, that my Eclipse's workspace must be moved inside Tomcat ROOT directory, along with all my projects. Is this true?

Comment: No. your eclipse workspace stays where it is now (probably in your profile). Eclipse|New Java Project| Uncheck use default location | select c:\apache-tomcat-x...\webapps\myproject

Comment: Yes very nice. But i figured out GWT rpc only works only if project.html file is put directly inside tomcat's root

Comment: Do you think it has to do with web.xml url? <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/project/greet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

Comment: the project html goes into the project directory and is accessed using http://localhost/myproject/project.html. You may need to change your project launch config, look at the parameters in Eclipse run configuration.

Comment: Yes correct, i tried this, but only [localhost/project.html] hierarchy works. I think it has to do with the URL pattern